# Ecto Changeset, required fields not validating on changes

Tags: elixir, ecto, changeset

learning Elixir/Ecto, and have hit a snag related to changesets. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a "domain model" struct that has some required fields. When I do a `put_change`, the returned changeset is still saying there's an error on the changeset (field missing), even though it is right there in the changes.

```
cset = Activity.changeset(%Activity{}, %{details: "Played in the snow", child_id: child_id}) 

#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{child_id: "ed553c30-38d2-4cb1-9029-eb2180c141cc",
   details: "Played in the snow"},
 errors: [relevant_date: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
  display_time: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #MyApp.Domain.Activity<>, valid?: false>
```

The above is to be expected. both `relevant_date` and `display_time` are missing, and as such the errors should be there.

```
cset |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:relevant_date, ~D[2016-12-31])

#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{child_id: "ed553c30-38d2-4cb1-9029-eb2180c141cc",
   details: "Played in the snow", relevant_date: ~D[2016-12-31]},
 errors: [relevant_date: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
  display_time: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Kidgenius.Domain.Activity<>, valid?: false>
```

This is the part that doesn't make any sense to me. `relevant_date` is **right there** on the changes field, and yet it's still telling me that `relevant_date can't be blank`.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** This is Ecto `2.1.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`put_change` doesn't perform validation, you need to pass updated changeset through `validate_required`, so it will try to perform validation on your updated state.

Hope that clarifies the problem a bit!

**EDIT**

Just for clarification:

```
# 1.
cset =
  Activity.changeset(
    %Activity{},
    %{details: "Played in the snow", child_id: child_id}
  )

# 2.
cset = Ecto.Changeset.put_change(cset, :relevant_date, ~D[2016-12-31])

# 3. This probably is something you currently have implemented
#    in your `Activity.changeset`, most likely as second setep
#    after `Ecto.cast/3`.
cset = Ecto.Changeset.validate_required(cset, [:relevant_date])
```

Comment: Thanks! This does answer my question.  Will running `validate_required` also run all the other validations on the changeeset? Is there an idiomatic way to "re-run" validations on a changeeset once you've changed the data?

Comment: Glad to help! In respect to your question - you could tackle that by extracting all validation rules to separate function (like `validate`), that would accept a `changeset`, which you could pipe through all _validating functions_, if that makes sense. The great thing about Elixir/Ecto is that you can compose whatever you need with plain functions. Take advantage of it!